# Is it possible to target element by several pseudo-classes via css selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I want to set style for disable button hover. I can reach this by targeting for example like:

```
input[disabled="disabled"]:hover
```

but what if I want to target disabled only child button input hover? Can I do something like

```
input[type="button"]:disabled:only-child:hover
```

**???**

Comment: Can you share your html for this?  Having multiple pseudo-classes is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in the way you are asking:

```
input[type=button]:disabled:only-child:hover
```

Works nice: http://jsfiddle.net/TekUR/

Comment: but why it didn't work when I tried? oO I probably should go to sleep ))